# Configured feign but on request timeout, it doesn't use given ErrorDecoder class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, feign

I am using Feign in my application to make an HTTP call. I have provided an ErrorDecoder class as well but when the request times out, the flow doesn't reach my ErrorDecoder class. What am I missing here? What I would like to do is throw a custom error from the errordecoder class and then catch it in GlobalExceptionHandler and return a 408 status code

#### FeignClient

```
@FeignClient(name="finacle-service" ,url = "${feign.client.url.finacleUrl}", configuration = FinacleProxyConfig.class)
public interface FinacleProxy {

  @PostMapping
  String getCif(@RequestBody String request);

  @PostMapping
  String updateFinaclePns(@RequestBody String request);


}
```

#### FeignConfigclass

```
public class FinacleProxyConfig {


  @Bean
  public static Logger.Level feignLoggerLevel() {
    return Logger.Level.FULL;
  }

  @Bean
  public static Request.Options requestOptions() {
    return new Request.Options(3000, 3000);
  }

  @Bean
  public static FinacleErrorDecoder errorDecoder(){
    return new FinacleErrorDecoder();
  }

}
```

#### application.properties

```
 spring.application.name = bds-intgeration-services
 eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
 eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
 spring.cloud.services.registrationMethod=direct

 
logging.level.org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter=DEBUG

 feign.httpclient.disableSslValidation=true
 feign.httpclient.enabled=false
 feign.okhttp.enabled=true

 feign.hystrix.enabled = false
```

#### Custom Error Decoder class

```
public class FinacleErrorDecoder implements ErrorDecoder {

  private final ErrorDecoder defaultErrorDecoder = new Default();
  @Override
  public Exception decode(String methodkey, Response response) {

    if(response.status() == 408){
       return FinacleTimedOutException.builder().message("Request timed out to finacle").build();
    }
    return defaultErrorDecoder.decode(methodkey, response);
  }
}
```

Comment: afaik the ErrorDecoder only looks for the http status. To catch a connection timeout you could catch the `RetryableException`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54258079/feign-errordecoder-not-invoked

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle feign client connection timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60180713/how-to-handle-feign-client-connection-timeout)