# How to handle feign client connection timeout

Tags: spring, timeout, feign

I have below code to check this error but I am not getting timeout error its going to else condition

```
Response response = null;
        try {
            response = client.getResponse(URI.create(uri), headers, reuest);
        } catch (Exception ex) {

            if(ex instanceof SocketTimeoutException){
                throw new ExternalClientException(Errors.TIMEOUT_ERROR);
            } else {
                throw new ExternalClientException(Errors.UNEXPECTED_ERROR);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to catch `feign.RetryableException` instead of `SocketTimeoutException`.

[javadoc](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/blob/master/core/src/main/java/feign/RetryableException.java)

Answer (score -2):

Please send all code of class. You need to provide class of "client" variable so people can help.

One more thing, instead of checking instance of exception in "catch" clause, you should use multiple catching like this:

```
Response response = null;
try {
    response = client.getResponse(URI.create(uri), headers, reuest);
} catch (SocketTimeoutException ex1) {
    throw new ExternalClientException(Errors.TIMEOUT_ERROR, ex1);
} catch (Exception ex2) {
    throw new ExternalClientException(Errors.UNEXPECTED_ERROR, ex2);
}
```

Comment: He mentioned in the title that he’s using Feign client